# location information sharing during device discovery over wifi p2p on android devices?

Tags: android, wifip2p

How can I share location information during device discovery over wifi p2p on android devices? I want the neighboring devices to share their own lat/long among themselves while they are discovering each other. Currently, I'm able to see all the discovered devices on a listview. Can I also store their lat/long there?

Comment: You need to enable GPS location, then get the position of the device... Then you need to find a way to send that information as part of the discovery process

Comment: Thanks cricket_007! I have already saved the geo information in individual devices but I'm actually looking for  "a way to send that information as a part of the discovery process". Are you pointing to add some methods to wifip2pmanager class? if so can you tell more?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that class. Just saying how I would generally approach the problem. As far as I know, what you're asking for is sending extra information as part of the wifi p2p protocols, which I'm not sure the available methods let you do